# Kendo DateTimePicker set value from json result

Tags: json, kendo-ui, kendo-datetimepicker

I have a big trouble with pasting a value in Kendo DateTimePicker inside Kendo Grid from json result. So I have two forms on page. In first I'm loading file:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetImportSalesModelFromFile", "ExportImport", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "GetImportSaleModelFromFileForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
     <input id="importFileInput" type="file" accept="text/csv" name="file" class="user-success" required>
     <input style="width: 100px;" type="submit" value="Add">
}
```

On form submit called function

```
$('#GetImportSaleModelFromFileForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", document.getElementById('importFileInput').files[0]);
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.send(fd);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
        AppendImportModel(JSON.parse(event.target.response));
    }, false);
});
```

In controller I get needed import model

```
    public ActionResult GetImportSalesModelFromFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        var importModel = _importService.ConstructSaleImportModel(file.InputStream, file.ContentType);
        return Json(importModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In function AppendImportModel I parse result and paste it in kendo grid in second form

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ImportSaleItemModel>().Name("ImportSalesGrid")
                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax())
                            .Events(x => x.DataBound("initMenus"))
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound(x => x.Goods.PictureId)
                                    .ClientTemplate("<img style='height: 50px;' src='" + Url.Action("Contents", "FileStorage", new { id = "#= Goods.PictureId #" }) + "'/>")
                                    .Title("")
                                    .Sortable(false)
                                    .HtmlAttributes(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "style", "padding: 3px !important; height: 52px !important; width:52px !important;" } });
                                columns.Bound(x => x.Goods.Title)
                                    .ClientTemplate("<a onclick='ShowInfoGoodWindow(#= Goods.Id #)'>#= Goods.Title #</a><br>" +
                                                    "<span><b>#= Goods.Article #</b> <descr>#= Goods.Description #</descr></span><br><input type='hidden' name='ImportedGoodList[#= index(data)#].Id' value='#= Goods.Id #' />")
                                    .Title("Description");
                                columns.Bound(x => x.Price)
                                    .ClientTemplate("<input class='priceEditor' maxlength='10' style='width:50px; text-align: center;' type='text' name='ImportedGoodList[#= index(data)#].Price' onkeypress='return isPriceKey(event)' oninput='$(this).get(0).setCustomValidity(clearValidation);' value='#=Price.ParsedValue #'>")
                                    .HtmlAttributes(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "style", "text-align: center;" } })
                                    .Title("Price");
                                columns.Bound(x => x.Discount)
                                    .ClientTemplate("<input class='discountEditor' maxlength='10' style='width:50px; text-align: center;' type='text' name='ImportedGoodList[#= index(data)#].Discount' onkeypress='return isPriceKey(event)' oninput='$(this).get(0).setCustomValidity(clearValidation);' value='#=Discount.ParsedValue #'>")
                                    .HtmlAttributes(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "style", "text-align: center;" } })
                                    .Title("Discount");
                                columns.Bound(x => x.DepartmentId)
                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "templateCell" })
                                    .ClientTemplate(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("Department#=LineId#").BindTo(Model.Departments).Value("#= DepartmentId #").ToClientTemplate().ToHtmlString())
                                    .Title("Department");
                                columns.Bound(x => x.SaleDateTime)
                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "templateCell" })
                                    .ClientTemplate(Html.Kendo().DateTimePicker().Name("SaleDateTime#=LineId#").Value("#= ConvertedSaleDateTime #").ToClientTemplate().ToHtmlString())
                                    .Title("Sale Date");
                                columns.Bound(x => x.SellerId)
                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "templateCell" })
                                    .ClientTemplate(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("Seller#=LineId#").BindTo(Model.Sellers).Value("#= SellerId #").ToClientTemplate().ToHtmlString())
                                    .Title("Seller");
                                columns.Bound(x => x.IsCashPayment)
                                    .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' id='IsCashPayment#=LineId#' checked='#= IsCashPayment.ParsedValue #' class='regular-checkbox'/><label for='IsCashPayment#=LineId#'></label> Yes")
                                    .Title("Is Cash Payment");
                            })
                            )
```

In all columns using "#= value #" works fine but not in this line

```
.ClientTemplate(Html.Kendo().DateTimePicker().Name("SaleDateTime#=LineId#").Value("#= ConvertedSaleDateTime #").ToClientTemplate().ToHtmlString())
```

"#= ConvertedSaleDateTime #" not changed on real value, but if I write

```
.ClientTemplate("#= ConvertedSaleDateTime #")
```

I will get right value "10/07/2013 13:15". And if I write

```
.ClientTemplate(Html.Kendo().DateTimePicker().Name("SaleDateTime#=LineId#").Value("10/07/2013 13:15").ToClientTemplate().ToHtmlString())
```

I will get Kendo DateTimePicker inside grid with value "10/07/2013 13:15"
How I can set value to this DateTimePicker from ConvertedSaleDateTime?
Please, help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem via jQuery. Maybe someone needs this solution or knows something more beautiful.
In client template of SaleDateTime columnt I wrote:

```
columns.Bound(x => x.SaleDateTime).ClientTemplate("<input class='saleDateTimeEditor' id='SaleDateTime#=index(data)#' name='ImportedSalesList[#=index(data)#].SaleDateTime' value='#= ConvertedSaleDateTime #'>")
```

And in DataBound event of my kendo grid I initialized all kendo DateTimePickers:

```
    $('.saleDateTimeEditor').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = new Date(Date.parse($(this).val()));
        $("#" + id).kendoDateTimePicker({
            value: value,
            max: new Date(Date.now())
        });
        $('#'+id).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
    });
```

ConvertedSaleDateTime is in format "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"